# Cannot run Bamboo build specs on Docker in Windows 10

Tags: java, docker, bamboo

When I run process Bamboo build specs in Docker container, I have error about missing/invalid path.

I have local installation of `Bamboo 6.9.1` in `Windows 10` machine.

```
Docker 18.09.2 with Hyper-V containers (default option)
```

docker settings:

-expose daemon on port 2375 without TLS

-local drive C: shared to container

In Bamboo - repository Stored Specs security settings :
Enable Repository Stored Specs - checked

Process Bamboo Specs in Docker -checked

Docker image(required) : 'atlassian/bamboo-specs-runner:6.9.1'.

When i'm trying to process build specs, I have error:

```
Processing Specs within Docker containerUnable to scan repository bamboo-specs gh (753665) for Bamboo Specs
com.atlassian.bamboo.repository.RepositoryException: Unable to scan repository bamboo-specs gh (753665) for Bamboo Specs
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.configuration.external.RepositoryStoredSpecsServiceImpl.lambda$runSpecsWithDocker$9(RepositoryStoredSpecsServiceImpl.java:864)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:48)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:26)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:17)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:41)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerRequestException: Request error: POST http://localhost:2375/containers/create?name=bamboo-specs-685e946f-716d-4b1d-a92e-35c3aa66aa42: 400, body: {"message":"the working directory '\\mnt\\input' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path"}
```

Comment: how did you solve this issue ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify with the development team that Docker on Windows is supported. While Windows does support windows, it requires different images and the Bamboo server code needs to be adapted as well.